# Тег audio и его свойства play() в react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как при клике допустим на тег li запустить музыку, как правильно прописать свойства play()? Как правильно использовать состояние для этого. Я только учусь React js-у, так что пример с кодом был-бы очень кстати. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58894830/15331960

Comment: Play() - это не свойство, а метод.

Answer (score 1):

> Я только учусь React js-у, так что пример с кодом был-бы очень кстати.

Например вот такой вариант с `audio` с простеньким управлением. Далее нужно читать что еще можно делать с этим тегом и добавлять элементы управления им...

P.S.
УРЛ трека взял какой-то наугад с интернета...

```js
const AudioPlayer = props => {
  const audioRef = React.useRef(null);
 
  const play = () => audioRef.current.play();
  const pause = () => audioRef.current.pause();
  const setVolume = value => audioRef.current.volume = value;
 
  return (
    <div>
      <audio ref={audioRef} src={props.src} controls></audio>
      <div>
        <button onClick={play}>Play</button>
        <button onClick={pause}>Pause</button>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" defaultValue="1" onChange={e => setVolume(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

//
function App() {
  return <section>
    <h1>Управление audio</h1>
    <AudioPlayer src={'https://music.arizona-rp.com/rodina/1691100307.mp3'} />
  </section>
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```